# Amazon S3 Copy 1.5 millions of objects with renaming of the folder

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have folder with 1.5 millions of objects (about 5 TB of data) which has folders with the next format 123-John.
I need to copy all these folders content in the new folders with renaming it to format 123.
I want to do it by the means of java.

Obviously I can't just do it one by one like this:

```
    ObjectListing objectListing = s3.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
        boolean processable = true;
        while (processable) {
            processable = objectListing.isTruncated();
            renameAndCopyOneByOne(objectListing.getObjectSummaries()); // this edits name and makes call to s3.copyObject()
            if (processable) {
                objectListing = s3.listNextBatchOfObjects(objectListing);
            }
        }
```

it would lead to making about 1.5 millions calls to

```
 s3.copyObject(bucket, sourceKey, bucket, destinationKey)
```

I wanted to do it with [batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops-create-job.html) , but the thing is that it could be done only with creating of manifest file in CSV format with format like

```
bucketName,keyName
```

But this is just manifest for the objects I want to make action to. I can't list locations where to save to and specify edited folder name. And also I still have to split CSV with 1.5 millions into smaller ones and create several request to S3 to create several jobs which would be not obvious to track.

Could you please give me a hint what from AWS tools would perfectly suffice all my needs for this task?

Comment: I am asking the AWS SDK team for any advice on this.

Comment: @smac2020 Thank you a lot! Really waiting for the response.

Comment: What do you mean by "split CSV with 1.5 millions into smaller ones"?

Comment: Why do you say "Obviously I can't just do it one by one"? Are you worried about the amount of time it would take? If so, you could send the Copy commands **in parallel** to reduce the time taken.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein "split CSV with 1.5 millions into smaller ones" - it is not desirable for me to have in memory and then upload to S3 CSV with 1.5 millions of lines. I presume it would be quite weighty.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein "Obviously I can't just do it one by one" - I don't want to make 1.5 millions of HTTP PUT requests to S3. I think it will be a lot even If I split it into let's say 150 threads.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  I just thought maybe there is some chance that batch is capable to be configured more in sophisticated way and I can set location places for every key in manifest as well. Or there is something like  s3.deleteObjects(deleteObjectsRequest) but for copying. If Java way is not suffice here what approach should I use instead then?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein And also if I try to split copying requests into 150 threads (let's say) It is not solving my problem with storing about 1.5 millions of Strings in memory. I think I will get Out of Memory error at some moment when every thread will have about 10000 of strings in it to send to s3.copy(). method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some time spent on how to do it properly I think the only way is to make such migration by some batch job from Java, to split the load.
Because AWS does not have proper tool for my case.